# Передача результата выполнения функции

Tags: javascript

Есть функция генерирующая сид внутри класса Creature. Ее результат должен присваивается свойству seed.

```
class Creature {
    constructor(seed){
        function searchForSeed(seed) {
            if (seed === undefined){
                return generateSeed();
            } else {
                return seed;
            }
        }
        this.seed = searchForSeed(seed);
    }
}
```

Почему this.seed получает вот это?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Код `generateSeed()`

```
function generateSeed() {
    let seed = Math.random().toFixed(10).split('');
    seed.shift();
    seed.shift();
    return seed.join('');
}
```

Вызов происходит через суперкласс:

```
class CreatureType extends Creature {
    constructor(){
        super(Creature);
    }
}

let a = new CreatureType();
```

Comment: Покажите код для `generateSeed`. Также покажите, как создаете экземпляр `Creature`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko добавил

Comment: Я не эксперт, но язык не js, а ts. Лучше вопрос поправить

Comment: @ArchDemon Это JS синтаксис классов из ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При вызове [`super` в конструкторе](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), в качестве аргументов должны передаваться аргументы для конструктора базового типа.

В данном случае - значение `seed`.

Однако в коде вопроса происходит вызов:

```
super(Creature);
```

То есть передается *сам класс **Creature***.

Вместо этого должен передаваться seed, либо ничего не передаваться.

```
class CreatureType extends Creature {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А в каком случае может понадобится вызов `super(Creature)`?

Comment: @brachkoff, только если конструктор базового класса должен принимать функцию (класс).